# Check whether lat/long combination reside within a polygon

Tags: mysql, polygon

I've been breaking my head for this already for a while. I need to check whether a lat/long position reside within a polygon through MySQL. According [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51869/how-to-find-out-whether-a-lat-long-position-resides-within-a-polygon) i should do it like this:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-33.7507, 151.1445)'), 
  ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON ((
  -33.7508 151.1444,
  -33.7505 151.1447,
  -33.7507 151.1450,
  -33.7509 151.1454,
  -33.7514 151.1449,
  -33.7508 151.1443,
  -33.7508 151.1444))'))
```

However this is returning me null. Any ideas? Im using MySQL 5.6.13

Comment: that post appear to be using postgresql

Comment: @Fabricator doesn't give me any errors though, just returns null

Comment: that is strange, because I got `FUNCTION ST_GeometryFromText does not exist` and according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971516/st-buffer-equivalent-for-circle-based-searches-in-mysql), mysql does not having this feature

Comment: @Fabricator maybe because i got mysql 5.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very cool. Didn't know mysql had this feature.
To construct a point, use no comma:

```
'POINT(-33.7507 151.1445)'
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/763)